# Resolucion con Prolog

Tags: prolog

Buenas tardes,

He encontrado un problema con mi profesor en la clase de Prolog.
Dice mi professor que podemos hacer una resolucion con el programa siguente

```
mag(paris,mag_a).
mag(paris,mag_b).
mag(lyon,mag_c).
mag(lyon,mag_d).
liste(M):-mag(V,M),write(M),write( situe_a ),write(V),nl,fail.
liste(M):-write(fin liste).
```

servido por el goal siguente:

```
liste(X)
```

y que da el resultado siguente:

```
   mag_a situe a paris
   mag_b situe a paris
   mag_c situe a lyon
   mag_d situe a lyon
   fin liste
   true.
```

Pero, en swish.swi, el software que compila Prolog online dicen que no es posible hacer eso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Entonces, quien puedo creer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo cuál es el problema que quieres resolver, pero si creo que en la última línea hay un error de sintaxis. Si envías dos parámetros a write deberían ir separados por coma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir,

```
liste(M):-write(fin, liste).
```

Comment: En efecto, quiero la lista de las tiendas ("magasins"). Y esta es, fue unaerror de sintaxis, no supe que no seria posible haber espacios en el write